# Is there a way to force the iOS Simulator to be case sensitive?

Tags: ios-simulator

I just got burned a second time in a year on case sensitivity of device versus simulator.  Assuming that this isn't a "bug" in the simulator (or at least not one that will be addressed by Apple), is there any way to force the simulator to be case sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to force it to be cases sensitive because it just uses whatever file system you give it.  If you want to use a case sensitive filesystem for the sim, you can create a new case sensitive FS and mount it at ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator or setup a symlink from that location to the mount point.

Note that you'll need to SIGKILL the CoreSimulatorService after doing that (or just reboot) to make sure it recreates fresh devices at the new location instead of thinking the old ones are still there.